# Python: removing multiple values from a list where using filters is more awkward

Tags: python

Trying to create a list of files with multiple extensions over which to iterate. Most of the answers on stack overflow involve filtering using lambda but I'm not sure how this can work in this case (just because of the way the iteration would be set up). So far I have

```
import fnmatch

excluded = ['*.py', '*.py~']

fileNames = []

for fileName in os.listdir('.'):
    fileNames.append(fileName)
    print fileNames

for p in excluded:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(fileName, p):
        fileNames.remove(fileName)
        print fileNames
```

Obviously the problem is that list.remove only removes the first instance and not all instances. What do you reckon would be the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably did not mean to indent the print statements. Otherwise you print the entire list again every time you add something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension )):

```
filtered = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if not any(fnmatch.fnmatch(x, p) for p in excluded)]
```

Alternatively, a more compact code using regular expressions:

```
filtered = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if not re.search(r'\.py~?$', x)]
```

or simply use `endswith`

```
excluded = ('.py', '.py~')
filtered = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if not x.endswith(excluded)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY):

```
for p in excluded:
    fileNames = [filename for filename in fileNames if not fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, p)]
```

You can do this even more nicely by using [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) as well:

```
fileNames = [filename for filename in fileNames if not any(fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, p) for p in excluded)]
```

Note that the list you are making is pointless, as `os.listdir()` returns a list anyway, so you can just do `fileNames = os.listdir()` to get the same result - or even place it in the list comprehension:

```
fileNames = [filename for filename in os.listdir() if not any(fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, p) for p in excluded)]
```

If you want to edit the values as you build up the list, you can do that too with the list comprehension.

Another alternative is the `fnmatch` module has [`fnmatch.filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter).

Answer (score 2):

```
def includefilename(fileName):
    for ex in excluded:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(fileName, ex):
            return False
    return True

fileNames = [fileName for fileName in fileNames if includefilename(fileName)]
```

Comment: You might as well invert the function and change the last line to `fileNames = filter(includefilename, fileNames)`.